# Posts do Wordpress em site html

Tags: html, wordpress

estou tentando colocar imagens do meu blog que está em Wordpress no meu site html

Meu código

```
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="col-md-4 ">
                            <div class="box-blog">
                                <img src="" >
                                <h4 class="hov"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                <span><i class="fa">&#xf073;</i> <?php the_time("d/m/Y"); ?></span>
                                <br><br>
                                <article>
                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                </article>
                                <div align="center">
                                    <a target="__blank" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><button class="btn btn-primary">Leia Mais</button></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
```

já tenho todo o corpo só falta a imagem mas não sei como coloca-la por favor me ajude.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');`, assim:

```php
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-md-4 ">
        <div class="box-blog">
            <!-- <img src="" > -->
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
            <h4 class="hov"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            <span><i class="fa">&#xf073;</i> <?php the_time("d/m/Y"); ?></span>
            <br><br>
            <article>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </article>
            <div align="center">
                <a target="__blank" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><button class="btn btn-primary">Leia Mais</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

ou usar `get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full');`, assim:

```php
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-md-4 ">
        <div class="box-blog">
            <?php $image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full'); ?>
            <?php if( $image ): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php endif; ?>
            <h4 class="hov"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            <span><i class="fa">&#xf073;</i> <?php the_time("d/m/Y"); ?></span>
            <br><br>
            <article>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </article>
            <div align="center">
                <a target="__blank" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><button class="btn btn-primary">Leia Mais</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Segue o link para a documentação:

- [the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/)
- [get_the_post_thumbnail_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/)